# TypeError: R.unless is not a function

Tags: jestjs, ramda.js

I have a function that looks like this:

```
export const maybeDate = R.unless(R.isNil, R.constructN(1, Date));
```

Typescript never gives me a hard time about this, but the moment I run it through Jest, I get this message with zero feedback on what is going on wrong:

```
TypeError: R.unless is not a function
```

It stops giving me problems the moment I change it to the following:

```
export const maybeDate = () => R.unless(R.isNil, R.constructN(1, Date));
```

However my app itself stops working.

Back in ramda's github, I was suggested to do

```
export const maybeDate = (v) => R.unless(R.isNil, R.constructN(1, Date))(v);
```

But this feels more of a workaround (as much as my crappy non-working solution was) than a solution.

What's the best way to fix this?

Currently all I have installed is this:

"ramda": "^0.27.1"

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, `Ramda 0.27.1` has the `unless` method.

```js
const isEven = (n) => n % 2 === 0;

const shoutOdds = R.unless(isEven, console.log.bind(null, 'this "%s" looks odd'));

shoutOdds(5);
shoutOdds(10); // not called
shoutOdds(7);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

---

if you use es modules,
please make sure to import the ramda's namespace this way: `import * as R from 'ramda'`

Comment: That is exactly the way I import Ramda. Although I don't know how to check if I use ES modules.